# Perform an action in onMessageReceived() - Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am trying to perform an Action after listening to the payload in the onMessageReceived() , The action I want to implement has a **ProgressBar** in its method so, it's throwing a null-pointer exception.

Below is my method `onMessageReceived()`.

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    roomAvailabilityHelper = new RoomAvailabilityHelper("");
                    roomAvailabilityHelper.endCurrentMeeting(new RoomAvailabilityActivity());
                    roomAvailabilityHelper.autoRefreshTimer(new RoomAvailabilityActivity());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Am working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Updated ->","Calendar updated");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Then the `autoRefreshTimer()` and `endCurrentMeeting()` are available in the RoomAvailabilityHelper` class. Below are the methods.

```
 public static void endCurrentMeeting(RoomAvailabilityActivity activity) {
            activity.progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            RoomAvailabilityHelper.updateRoomCalendarEvents(activity.mDisposables,
                    false, activity, 2000);
            activity.runOnUiThread(() -> new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                MeetingRoomDetailFragment meetingRoomDetailFragment = (MeetingRoomDetailFragment)
                        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.frame_room_availability_details);
                if (meetingRoomDetailFragment != null && activity.sharedPreferences.getString(
                        CountryActivity.SHARED_ROOM_CHECKED_IN, null) == null) {
                    meetingRoomDetailFragment.displayCheckInScreen();
                }
                activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }, 3000));
        }


    public static void autoRefreshTimer(RoomAvailabilityActivity activity) {
            final int timedPeriod = 300000;
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                endCurrentMeeting(activity);
                autoRefreshTimer(activity);
            }, timedPeriod);
        }
```

Below is the error am getting :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.andela.mrm.room_availability.RoomAvailabilityHelper.endCurrentMeeting(RoomAvailabilityHelper.java:280)
        at com.andela.mrm.notifications.Notifications$1.run(Notifications.java:40)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
```

So am looking for a way of Connecting an **Activity** in the `onMessageReceived()`, but I can't get it. That's why am getting a **null pointer exception** on the **ProgressBar**, due to the **Activity**,

Comment: You are passing object of your activity that doesn't mean that your progress bar is initialized.

Comment: So what could be the good approach @PratikButani?

Comment: Generally no one use `Progressbar`  while receiving Notification.

Comment: No it's not like that, the thing is after receiving a notification , I check for the payload , if it exists , then I reload my activity , but this reloading needs an Activity to be there for the progresBar.

Comment: So you can use [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: Isn't there any other way, of calling the Activity in the `onMessageReceived()` other than eventbus?

Comment: forget everything and look at this `new RoomAvailabilityActivity()` you cannot do this. Why not? Because that's not how activities work

Comment: @TimCastelijns, am really stuck , how can I go around on this , that's why I asked. because when I debugged my code it was null.

Comment: I also tried to come up with a constructor inorder to get the Activity after making the instatiation of the class to the `RoomAvailabilityActivity` , but it didn't work out successfully.

Comment: read the activity documentation. You cannot instantiate them yourself, the system does this

Comment: why not u put `autofreshtimer()` and another function into the same file of ur `onMessageReceived()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is use `LocalBroadcastManager` .So when you received the event in `onMessageReceived()` in your Firebase service file,it trigger the function in your `Activity` and call your function inside the `Activity`.

In your `Activity` of your `ProgressBar`

```
private BroadcastReceiver pushMessageBroadCastReceiver;
//here receive the broadcast from Firebase message,then your thing

//add this inside onCreate()
pushMessageBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(AppConfig.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {

                //Here your receive the data from onMessageReceived()
                //do your thing here
                Log.d("Activity","Is triggerred here")
            }
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(pushMessageBroadCastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(AppConfig.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(pushMessageBroadCastReceiver);
    }
```

In your `AppConfig` class (If dont have,create one)

```
// broadcast receiver intent filters
 public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification";
```

In your `onMessageReceived()` add the code below,from here you trigger the `LocalBroadcastManager` which in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //here you trigger the LocalBroadcastManager in your activity
    Intent pushNotification = new Intent(AppConfig.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question would be , which kind of data , do I need to pass here `pushNotification.putExtra("your_data", data);` ?

Comment: Because me I thought I woiuld just place my action in the `onRecieve()` ?

Comment: if u dont have data to pass,then no need to pass anything

Comment: Actually , I have Implemented what you said and I first placed a notification in the `onReceive()`, but it didn't come, after there was a payload in the `onMessageReceived()` am wondering why